# CSS - DIV not scrolling to the bottom, when height is 100%

Tags: css

I'm trying to make a mobile experience similar to toyota.com's website. Basically I'd like to have the menu's DIV appear, and have a scroll bar for the overflow. I've set the HTML, and body tag to 100%... but I see that the menu is not reaching the bottom. It's not quite reaching the bottom, because the header's height. However, I don't know how to fix this. I've seen this asked so many times, but the cases appear to be different than my own circumstances.

If at all possible, may you take a look at my JSFiddle? It can be found at: https://jsfiddle.net/x5cry4Lx/5/

My existing CSS (as a reference)...:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
body.mobile-nav-open {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.starter-template {
  text-align: center;
}
section#header {
  height: auto;
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  height: 36px;
}
section#header a.openNav,
section#header a.closeNav { 
  font-size: 11px;
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
section#header a.openNav i,
section#header a.closeNav i {
  display: block;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
section#header a.closeNav {
  display: none;
}
body.mobile-nav-open section#header a.openNav {
  display: none;
}
body.mobile-nav-open section#header a.closeNav {
  display: block;
}
section#mobile-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
section#mobile-menu li {
  list-style: none;
}
section#mobile-menu li a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

And my HTML (as a reference)...:

```
<section id="header">
  <div class="pull-right">
    <a href="#" class="openNav"><i class="fa fa-bars"></i>Menu</a>
    <a href="#" class="closeNav"><i class="fa fa-close"></i>Close</a>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</section>
<section id="mobile-menu">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
      <ul class="list-unstyled">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: For semantic reasons, use `nav` instead of `section` for your menu.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There are different ways to achieve this.

**1. Using `calc`. Where `67px` is the height of the header.**

Changes:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

section#mobile-menu {
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100% - 67px);
  background: #fff;
  z-index: 999;
  display: none;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

**2. Making your header `position:absolute;` and give the body `padding-top:67px;`.**

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/0d7hb9o0/)**

Changes:

```css
* {
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

body {
    padding-top:67px;
    margin:0;
}

section#header {
  padding: 15px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
  background: #fff;
  height: 67px;
  position:absolute;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  width:100%;  
}
```

Comment: That's awesome. I didn't even know of the calc property! I've had so many instances where that would have been great to know. Thank you so very much!

Comment: I also added an another solution :)

Answer (score 1):

I found an easier way to do it:

```
max-height: 100vh; 
overflow-y: scroll;
```